# Replacing text with smiley image using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please Guys, I am new to Jquery. I have been searching for a suitable help since last week but I can't find any. I want to replace a text with a smiley image using jquery but I have no idea how to run this. For example, I want this text "I am feeling `:happy;`" to be replaced with "I am feeling `<img src='happy_face.gif' />`" and "He is `:sick;`" to be replaced with "He is `<img src='sick.gif' />`".
Here is what I have gotten so far but it still displays the text instead of the image:

```
    :)   :(
<script src="js/jscript.js"></script>
<script>
var emotes = [
    [':happy;', 'happy.gif'],
    [':sick;', 'sick.gif']
];

function applyEmotesFormat(body){
    for(var i = 0; i < emotes.length; i++){
        body = body.replace(new RegExp(emotes[i][0], 'gi'), '<img src="emotes/' + emotes[i][1] + '">');
    }
    return body;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We request that you post what approaches you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple.
You only need one line to find and replace string instances in the HTML:
`$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/:happy;/g,'<div class="happy-face"></div>'));`

This sets `$("body").html()` to the `$("body").html()` with `:happy;` replaced with `<div class="happy-face"></div>`.

`/:happy;/g` is RegEx to find the string `:happy;` globally (`g`)

https://jsfiddle.net/heowqt1u/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
var a = [[':happy;','<img src="happy_face.gif" />'],[':sick;',"<img src='sick.gif' />"]];
a.forEach(function(item) {
    $('p').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(text.replace(item[0], item[1]));
    });
});
```

Working example here: [Smiley codes replace](http://codepen.io/chesheer/pen/xVazwN)