# Replacing text in a jQuery string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I want to replace some text in a jQuery string with images for example :

```
//original string
str = "This is a message from peter to john";

//After replacement
str = "This is a message from <img src='peter.jpg'> to <img src='john.jpg'>";
```

In php it can be done like this:

```
$string = strtr($str, array('peter'=>'<img src="peter.jpg" />', 'john'=>'<img src="john.jpg" />'));
```

Please is there a similar way to do this in jQuery just like the php method. Or any better idea to achieve this?

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36870625/2645347) to one of your previous questions is in essence what you are looking for

Comment: This really has very little (if anything) to do with jQuery.

Comment: Have you at least tried Googling this on your own? This is the type of question that can be solved by quickly consulting the JS documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
var str = "This is a message from peter to john";
str = str.replace(/\b(?:peter|john)\b/g, "<img src='$&.jpg'>");
console.log(str)
```

Comment: I think I prefer your method its easier. But what if the texts I want to replace has some characters like this `":peter;"` or `":john;"` How do I escape the `:` and `;`

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE : `/:(?:peter|:john);/g` ,

Comment: But I end up having this `<img src=':peter;.jpg' />` instead of `<img src='peter.jpg' />` please how do I take out the `:` and `;`?

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE : do it like : `str.replace(/:(peter|john);/g, "<img src='$1.jpg'>");`

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript `replace()` method like this

```js
var str = "This is a message from peter to john";
str = str.replace("peter","<img src='peter.jpg'>").replace("john","<img src='john.jpg'>");
console.log(str);
```