# how to convert textarea value into meaningful content without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting value typed, from `textarea` and pasting into a div. Typed value might contain smileys. In these case smileys needed to be converted into presentable smileys rather than just copy paste typed text as it is now.

```
var composer = $('[data-textarea]');
var message = $.trim(composer.val());
var wrapper = $('[data-wrapper]');

here the smileys has to be converted
wrapper.append(message);
```

Note: I do not want to play replacing the possible smileys like in these posts:
[Replacing text with smiley image using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869488/replacing-text-with-smiley-image-using-jquery)

I want jquery itself to translate to meaningful smileys depending on the browser setting.

**Do not want replacing like this:**

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/:sick;/g,'<div class="sick-face"></div>'));
```

Comment: Do you mean that users can paste something like `:)` in, or rather a Unicode character like ? And what do you mean by 'presentable smileys'? The display of Unicode characters depends on the device, browser and installed fonts of users, for example.

Comment: @Justastudent, I mean if I type :) in the textarea, when appending to a div , it should look like the unicode character

Comment: If I reload the page, obviously its translated to unicode, but I need it works the same way even without reload

Comment: Can I ask you what browser/device you are using? I've never seen automatic replacement of smileys with emojis before.

Comment: just chrome and firefox on pc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up the unicode representation of your desired smileys and use it to create a mapping of "text to unicode" couples, then replace the input text with that. I have found this handy little website for smileys but there are many more : http://character-code.com/emoticons-html-codes.php.

Here is a small setup and script added to the body tag to do exactly what I described above:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var smileyMap = {
    ':)': '&#128522;',
    ':(': '&#128547;'
      // etc...
  };
  // on every character added
  $('#myInput').keyup(function(value) {
    // get the whole value
    var progressiveText = $('#myInput').val();
    // replace textual smileys with unicode representation
    for (var key in smileyMap) {
      while (progressiveText.indexOf(key) >= 0)
        progressiveText = progressiveText.replace(key, smileyMap[key]);
    }
    // update the html
    $('#myDiv').html(progressiveText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="myInput" type="text" name="text" />
</div>
<br />
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Good answer! I took the liberty to convert your answer to use a snippet, so it can be run here, and also added a while() to make sure it does multiple replace.